# How to enable a DataGridView on an UserControl

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I want to add a DataGridView to an UserControl. So I drag & dropped it there and customized all properties as I wished for. Then I dragged and dropped said UserControl on a Form. Now when I start the Form the UserControl and also its contained DataGridView are shown. However the DataGridView does not show any data besides the column headers.

If I drag and drop a DataGridView on a Form directly (w/o using an UserControl) and customize it in the very same way that I do when trying it on the UserControl then it shows me a filled DataGridView.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you bind the datagridview to a datasource and how?

Comment: After dropping the DataGridView it always asks me which data soruce to use (or if there isnt if I want to vreate a new one). So yes I do define the data source in both cases. Like I said. I follow exactly the SAME steps/procedures

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

on loading my UserControl I have to add this

```
Private Sub MyCtrl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.MyDataTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Tools_db_reminders.MyData)
End Sub
```

This is being done automatically when dropping a GridView on a Form but it seems this does not happen automatically when I drop a DataGridView on a UserControl